# Pattern match in Bash script to zero-pad file names

Tags: bash

I want to zero-pad file names. I'm using this script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417979/batch-rename-sequential-files-by-padding-with-zeroes).

```
#!/bin/bash
num=`expr match "$1" '[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*'`
paddednum=`printf "%03d" $num`
echo ${1/$num/$paddednum}
```

This script output file name with zero-pad for former numbers:

```
$ zeropad "folder01/01.jpg"
folder001/01.jpg
```

But I want to zero-pad latter numbers like this:

```
$ zeropad "folder01/01.jpg"
folder01/001.jpg
```

How can I do it? And is there a web page that I can see a lot of examples of Bash pattern matches?

Comment: Open to zsh? `zmv 'folder01/(*).jpg' 'folder01/${(l:3::0:)1}.jpg'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
path="folder01/01.jpg"
dir=$(dirname "$path")
file=$(basename "$path")
ext=${file##*.}
file=${file%.*}
# assume file is composed of digits here
printf -v newname "%s/%03d.%s" "$dir" $file "$ext"
echo "$newname"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should separate `folder01/01.jpg` in two strings: `folder01` and `01.jpg`, make the changes to `01.jpg` and finally put them again together:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=`echo $1 | cut -d/ -f 1`    #or dir=`dirname $1`
file=`echo $1 | cut -d/ -f 2`   #or file=`basename $1`

num=`expr match "$file" '[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*'`
paddednum=`printf "%03d" $num`
echo "$dir/${file/$num/$paddednum}"
```

---

And Google is your friend to find many web pages (not just one) where you can see a lot of examples of Bash pattern matches. In fact this kind of questions are [off-topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) here.

Comment: How exactly is a Bash question off-topic here?

Comment: @JosephR. I was referring at the last question: *a web page that I can see a lot of examples of Bash pattern matches*.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see a regular expressions problem, my first instinct is Perl:

```
for file in folder01/*.jpg;do
    echo "$file"|perl -pe 's/([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)\Z/sprintf "%03d%s",$1,$2/e'
done
```

This doesn't assume that your file's name is made up of digits only.